# Busca por determinado(s) registro(s) não executa a filtragem em tabela utilizando JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho uma tabela que lista todas as compras feitas de determinados produtos de seus fornecedores.

- O seguinte campo faz a inserção do(s) produto(s) procurado(s).

**`<p> Procurar produto do fornecedor: <input id="nome" /> </p>`**

Que ao ser digitado deve retornar o registro de determinado produto. Só que **não está retornando o registro esperado**. Na verdade parece que **está filtrando o nome do(s) fornecedor(es) e não do(s) produto(s)**.

O campo que estou falando que quero **usar como parâmetro de busca é o campo `Produto` que possui o trecho `echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['produto_nome'].'</td>';`**.

A variável **`var filtro = document.getElementById('nome');`** deve filtrar o nome dos produtos.

---

- Código PHP que faz o INNER JOIN das tabelas `itens_compra_fornecedor`, `produto` e `fornecedor`.

```
<?php

    require_once '../conn/connection.php';  

    try {

        $selecao = "SELECT itens_compra_fornecedor.cd_itens_compra_fornecedor, 
        fornecedor.nome AS fornecedor_nome, produto.nome AS produto_nome, 
        produto.marca, produto.codigo_barra, produto.cor, produto.tamanho, 
        produto.genero, produto.quantidade, produto.valor_compra, produto.valor_revenda,
        itens_compra_fornecedor.data_compra FROM itens_compra_fornecedor
        INNER JOIN fornecedor ON (fornecedor.cd_fornecedor = itens_compra_fornecedor.cd_fornecedor)
        INNER JOIN produto ON (produto.cd_produto = itens_compra_fornecedor.cd_produto)";
        $seleciona_dados = $conexao->prepare($selecao);
        $seleciona_dados->execute();
        $linhas = $seleciona_dados->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } catch (PDOException $falha_selecao) {
        echo "A listagem de dados não foi feita".$falha_selecao->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

- Tabela que mostra os registros e campo para buscar registro(s) de produto(s).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Listar itens de compra </title>
</head>
<body>

<p> Procurar produto do fornecedor: <input id="nome" /> </p>
    <table id="lista" border="1">
        <tr> <td> ID <td> Fornecedor <td> Produto <td> Marca <td> Código de barra 
        <td> Cor <td> Tamanho <td> Gênero <td> Quantidade <td> Valor de compra 
        <td> Valor de revenda <td> Data da compra </tr>
        <?php 
            // Loop para exibir as linhas
            foreach ($linhas as $exibir_colunas){
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['cd_itens_compra_fornecedor'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['fornecedor_nome'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['produto_nome'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['marca'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['codigo_barra'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['cor'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['tamanho'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['genero'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['quantidade'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>R$'.$exibir_colunas['valor_compra'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>R$'.$exibir_colunas['valor_revenda'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($exibir_colunas['data_compra'])).'</td>';
                echo '</tr>'; echo '</p>';
            }
        ?>
    </table>  
</body>
</html>
```

- Código JS que faz a filtragem da busca de determinado(s) registro(s)

```
<script>
    // JS que retorna a filtragem do nome do produto comprado do fornecedor
    var filtro = document.getElementById('nome');
    var tabela = document.getElementById('lista');
    filtro.onkeyup = function() {
        var nomeFiltro = filtro.value.toLowerCase();
        for (var i = 1; i < tabela.rows.length; i++) {
            var conteudoCelula = tabela.rows[i].cells[1].innerText;
            var corresponde = conteudoCelula.toLowerCase().indexOf(nomeFiltro) >= 0;
            tabela.rows[i].style.display = corresponde ? '' : 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primeiro gostei da sua solução para economizar processamento do servidor e transferências de dados.
Segundo troque o cells[1] por cells[2]

Comment: Agora entendi: ```cd_itens_compra_fornecedor = cell[0], fornecedor_nome = cell[1], produto_nome = cell[2];```

Comment: Obrigado cara, eu realmente não havia percebido as posições da ```cell[]``` que influenciam na filtragem dos dados solicitados.